# How should we structure App with Domain-Driven Design in mind?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

We are building an ERP with 7+ distinct bounded contexts. Our concern is how to structure the application. We have looked at a few architectures like the onion and the n-layer architecture. 
A few questions have emerged

1. Should every bounded context form a system of sorts? With this I mean, should we have the following layers in each of the contexts, Presentation (UI), Application Services, Domain and Infrastructure. If so, at what point do they integrate?
2. How do we create a composite application using ASP.NET MVC like one offered by prism using WPF?

Answer (score 2):

> Should every bounded context form a system of sorts?

Yes. Every bounded context has its ubiquitous language. Distinct bounded contexts have relationships with each other via translation maps.

> With this I mean, should we have the following layers in each of the contexts, Presentation (UI), Application Services, Domain and Infrastructure. If so, at what point do they integrate?

A layered architecture is one approach. Another one that fits well with hosting a bounded context is the [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) with the domain model (including business logic) in the very center and adapters for user interfaces (web, mobile, ...), databases, REST clients, and so on.